# How to resolve Unsatisfied Link Error in android?

Tags: android

I am using sandroProxy lib in my application to make proxy server to listen request and responses from and to android device, got following exception, how to resolve it?

```
12-17 11:09:28.568: E/AndroidRuntime(10473): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load socketdest from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.sandroproxy.plugin-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/org.sandroproxy.plugin-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
12-17 11:09:28.568: E/AndroidRuntime(10473):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:358)
12-17 11:09:28.568: E/AndroidRuntime(10473):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
12-17 11:09:28.568: E/AndroidRuntime(10473):    at org.sandroproxy.utils.NetworkHostNameResolver.<clinit>(NetworkHostNameResolver.java:48)
12-17 11:09:28.568: E/AndroidRuntime(10473):    at org.sandroproxy.plugin.gui.MainActivity$1$1.run(MainActivity.java:98)
```

Answer (score 0):

This error could be because it is failed to load the third party library. Could you please check whether the library is present in the specified path or not.If it is not copy library .so files .

Comment: I don't know how to check the files specified path, can give little more explanation on it..

Comment: What is the format of the sandroProxy lib. Is it a jar file or is it a .so file?

Comment: By the way i am trying to be act as a proxy for all requests and responses from and to android(like man in middle)ex fiddler.. am not getting any idea about it, i am very glad if any suggest on this.

Comment: its project cloned from git

Comment: I think it is because either of two reason,                                  1. You are missing library files from git. 2. library is not included properly. For second case , If you are working in eclipse , Right click your project --> properties-->java build path --> add external jar --> <browse to third party jar lib that you want to use>                                                                    Click "Order and Export" tab of the same window and check the lib just now you have added. Then Click OK. Rebuild app and Run again.

Answer (score 0):

socketdest is native library build in sandroproxylib project. make sure that is build

https://code.google.com/p/sandrop/source/browse/projects/?name=master#projects%2FSandroProxyLib%2Fjni%2Fsocketdest

Comment: Yes but i dont know how to build a library project.. i am very glad if you suggest on it, i keep trying to build that but still not getting proper solution..